# Control order of plotting on Seaborn plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot residuals on a linear regression plot. It works, with only one caveat. There is an unpleasant looking overlap between residuals and data points. Is there a way to tell matplotlib to plot the residuals first followed by Seaborn plot. I tried changing the order of code, but it didn't help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import *
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10])
y = np.array([-3, 0, 4, 5, 9, 5, 7, 7, 12])
dat = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

linear_model = LinearRegression()
linear_model.fit(X=x, y=y)
pred = linear_model.predict(x)

for ix in range(len(x)):
    plot([x[ix], x[ix]], [pred[ix], y[ix]], '#C9B97D')

g = sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=dat, ci=None, fit_reg=True)
sns.set(font_scale=1.1)
g.figure.set_size_inches(6, 6)
sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.despine()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument you are looking for is `zorder`. This allows you to control which object appears on top in your figure.

For [`regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) you have to use the argument `scatter_kws` which is a dictionary of arguments to be passed to `plt.scatter` which is used under the hood.

Your `sns.regplot` becomes:

```
g = sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=dat, ci=None, fit_reg=True,
                scatter_kws={"zorder":10, "alpha":1})
```

Note that I've set `alpha` to 1 so that the markers are not transparent

[image]

Comment: Awesome, you beat me.  I'll delete. Plus, your explanation is better.  +1